# Сортировка слиянием

Tags: сортировка

Нужен алгоритм сортировки слиянием. Называется сортировка слиянием с делением на секции. Но название может быть вам и не знакомо. Главное принцип сортировки.
Массив разбивается на возрастающие и убывающие секции, а потом они сливаются. т е пока элементы массива убываеют отделяем в одну секцию, как только начинают возрастать отделяем в другу. и так делим весь массив. Кто нибудь знает чтото подобное? Помогите пожалуйста

Answer (score 1):

> [Сортировка слиянием](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC) — алгоритм сортировки, который упорядочивает списки  в определённом порядке. Сначала задача разбивается на несколько подзадач меньшего размера. Затем эти задачи решаются с помощью рекурсивного вызова или непосредственно, если их размер достаточно мал. Наконец, их решения комбинируются, и получается решение исходной задачи.

Answer (score 1):

Сортировка слиянием (Merge sort) — Сложность алгоритма: O(n log n); требуется O(n) дополнительной памяти; выстраиваем первую и вторую половину списка отдельно, а затем — сливаем упорядоченные списки.

Посмотрите в Википедии [здесь](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8) и [подробно здесь](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC)  (все нормально и подробно описано).